# How do I register a MediatR post processor

Tags: .net-core, mediatr

I would like to try the new pipeline feature in MediatR: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors

I tried the following, but it does not get executed

```
services.AddMediatR();                    
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), typeof(PostHandler<,>));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is only your post-processor not executed? or the handler? it would help if you could show some code.

Comment: The other standard handlers are executed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to register the behavior associated with post-processors, like [this unit test](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/8f1033e7b26f411dcea04256c03aeb4f2c6a50f0/test/MediatR.Tests/Pipeline/RequestPostProcessorTests.cs#L52) shows.

Your registration code would look like:

```cs
services.AddMediatR();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), typeof(PostHandler<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>));
```

That [behavior](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/8f1033e7b26f411dcea04256c03aeb4f2c6a50f0/src/MediatR/Pipeline/RequestPostProcessorBehavior.cs) will get all the post-processors you registered and execute them.

**Edit**

After a comment about the post-processor running twice, I had a look at the code that registers MediatR in the ASP.NET Core built-in DI container, and it turns out instances of `IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>` and `IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>` are automatically registered as you can see [here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/c676c96f7912fe449f82882b021be8aeeddf15a6/src/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L265). What's left to do to get them running in the pipeline is just register the associated behavior. So the necessary registration is then:

```cs
services.AddMediatR();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>));
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. registering the behavior as you suggest makes the Posthandler run, but it executes twice. Any ide why?

Comment: yep, I edited my answer. I find it weird to register the processors but not the associated behaviors. I might open an issue on GitHub some time.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue as Larsi in the comment above. My code looked like this

`services.AddScoped<IPipelineBehavior<AddMessageRequest, MessageResponse>, RequestPostProcessorBehavior<AddMessageRequest, MessageResponse>>();`

but the behaviour still executed twice. My solution was to simply not register it manually, seems like the registration is handled otherwise now.

In my case `services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` was enough.

Would be nice if someone could expand on why this is.

Comment: MediatR takes cares of DI registration for you of `IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> and IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>`.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this in case it helps other people (and also for my future self).

Due to how our project is architectured (our pipeline behaviors and post processors are located in a different assembly than our request handlers) I was trying to avoid using `MediatRServiceConfiguration` extension methods provided by the MeditR library but register them directly with `AddTransient` as it seems it was the old fashion way => BIG MISTAKE !

I stumbled on various different issues, mainly, **I was able to hit only one pipeline behavior**.

I gave up trying to be *smart* and I used MediatR extension methods instead but the configuration didn't go as smooth as I thought. I had issues with the configuration of my post processor.

Here is an example of what I came up with

```cs
services.AddMediatR(cfg => 
{
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(
        typeof(ServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly,
        typeof(LoggingPostProcessor<,>).Assembly
    );
    cfg.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CommandValidatorBehavior<,>));
    cfg.AddOpenRequestPostProcessor(typeof(LoggingPostProcessor<,>));
    cfg.AutoRegisterRequestProcessors = false;
});
```

`AutoRegisterRequestProcessors` is a [new property added in version 12.2.0](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/commit/8b1ee39fe29fd12c8042d22f9fd1a969b5fcbc16)
Maybe I don't understand fully how it works or maybe at this point it's still a bit buggy. The only thing I know is that I had to set it to `false` and explicitly use the `AddOpenRequestPostProcessor` method in order to get it working correctly (with different configurations, either my post processor was never hit or it was hit twice !).

I hope this will help other people. I must admit I spent quite some time on this issue.